# Handle redis connection reset

Tags: python, redis

We are facing `[Errno 54] Connection reset by peer` at very random in our application and looks like it is being triggered by redis server than client. Python's redis client have `backoff` strategy implementation but it's unable to handle this scenario.

There are github issues on official repo as well and many people commented recently confirming this problem.

- [Random ConnectionErrors (104, Connection reset by peer)
  #1186](https://github.com/redis/redis-py/issues/1186)
- [redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error while reading from socket: (104, 'Connection reset by peer') #1439](https://github.com/redis/redis-py/issues/1439)

##### Step to reproduce

```
$ ipython
# in python client
import redis
from redis.retry import Retry
from redis.exceptions import (TimeoutError, ConnectionError)
from redis.backoff import ExponentialBackoff

# connect client with exponential backoff retry
client = redis.StrictRedis(retry=Retry(ExponentialBackoff(cap=10, base=1), 25), retry_on_error=[ConnectionError, TimeoutError, ConnectionResetError], health_check_interval=1)

client.keys()
# print all keys
```

Now reset connection directly from redis server

```
$ redis-cli
RESET
```

Wait for 120 second or more and run client again

```
# in client
client.keys()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionResetError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-011ce9f936fc> in <module>
----> 1 client.keys("rq*")

~/path-to-python-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py in keys(self, pattern, **kwargs)
   1386         For more information check https://redis.io/commands/keys
   1387         """
-> 1388         return self.execute_command("KEYS", pattern, **kwargs)
   1389 
   1390     def lmove(self, first_list, second_list, src="LEFT", dest="RIGHT"):

~/path-to-python-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/client.py in execute_command(self, *args, **options)
   1168         pool = self.connection_pool
   1169         command_name = args[0]
-> 1170         conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
   1171 
   1172         try:

~/path-to-python-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py in get_connection(self, command_name, *keys, **options)
   1315             # closed. either way, reconnect and verify everything is good.
   1316             try:
-> 1317                 if connection.can_read():
   1318                     raise ConnectionError("Connection has data")
   1319             except ConnectionError:

~/path-to-python-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py in can_read(self, timeout)
    793         if not sock:
    794             self.connect()
--> 795         return self._parser.can_read(timeout)
    796 
    797     def read_response(self, disable_decoding=False):

~/path-to-python-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py in can_read(self, timeout)
    315 
    316     def can_read(self, timeout):
--> 317         return self._buffer and self._buffer.can_read(timeout)
    318 
    319     def read_response(self, disable_decoding=False):

~/path-to-python-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py in can_read(self, timeout)
    222 
    223     def can_read(self, timeout):
--> 224         return bool(self.length) or self._read_from_socket(
    225             timeout=timeout, raise_on_timeout=False
    226         )

~/path-to-python-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py in _read_from_socket(self, length, timeout, raise_on_timeout)
    192                 sock.settimeout(timeout)
    193             while True:
--> 194                 data = self._sock.recv(socket_read_size)
    195                 # an empty string indicates the server shutdown the socket
    196                 if isinstance(data, bytes) and len(data) == 0:

ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

Running it second time works perfectly, though it should have taken care by Retry strategy.

```
client.keys()
# prints all keys
```

configuration

```
redis server - 6.2.6
python redis - 4.1.0
```

We can write our own try/catch around redis client, but we are using some libraries like `rq` and `flask-cache` which uses redis internally and have no interface to modify it's flow.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I end up writing a custom class of Redis which retries on failure. Sharing it here in case anyone finds it useful.

```py
import redis
import logging

from retry import retry

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class RedisCustom(redis.Redis):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RedisCustom, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @retry(ConnectionResetError, delay=0.1, tries=5)
    def set(self, key, value, ex=None, px=None, nx=False, xx=False):
        return super(RedisCustom, self).set(key, value, ex, px, nx, xx)

    @retry(ConnectionResetError, delay=0.1, tries=5)
    def get(self, name):
        return super(RedisCustom, self).get(name)

    @retry(ConnectionResetError, delay=0.1, tries=5)
    def delete(self, *names):
        return super(RedisCustom, self).delete(*names)

    @retry(ConnectionResetError, delay=0.1, tries=5)
    def hset(self, name, key=None, value=None, mapping=None):
        return super(RedisCustom, self).hset(name, key, value, mapping)

    @retry(ConnectionResetError, delay=0.1, tries=5)
    def hmset(self, name, mapping):
        return super(RedisCustom, self).hmset(name, mapping)

    @retry(ConnectionResetError, delay=0.1, tries=5)
    def hgetall(self, name):
        return super(RedisCustom, self).hgetall(name)

    @retry(ConnectionResetError, delay=0.1, tries=5)
    def scan_iter(self, match=None, count=None, _type=None, **kwargs):
        return super(RedisCustom, self).scan_iter(match, count, _type, **kwargs)

    @retry(ConnectionResetError, delay=0.1, tries=5)
    def hdel(self, name, *keys):
        return super(RedisCustom, self).hdel(name, *keys)

    @retry(ConnectionResetError, delay=0.1, tries=5)
    def keys(self, pattern="*", **kwargs):
        return super(RedisCustom, self).keys(pattern, **kwargs)

    @retry(ConnectionResetError, delay=0.1, tries=5)
    def info(self, section=None, **kwargs):
        return super(RedisCustom, self).info(section, **kwargs)

    @retry(ConnectionResetError, delay=0.1, tries=5)
    def ping(self, **kwargs):
        return super(RedisCustom, self).ping(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set a healtcheck value,

`client = redis.Redis(..., health_check_interval=30)`

it will reestablish the connection.
More details in https://github.com/redis/redis-py/issues/1186

Answer (score -1):

Try using a connection Pool as it will keep alive and automatically attempt to recover in the background. In the REPL

```
import redis
pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host="localhost", port=6379)
r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)
r.ping()
```

In another shell you can test by running redis-cli

```
client LIST
client kill IP:PORT
```

Then run the

```
r.ping
```

And you should see a new connection in the redis-cli

```
client LIST
```

Comment: It's not working with `RESET` event. And redis internally uses pool by default if not specified.